# Extracting site location from original MODIS sinusoidal projection from Google Earth Engine?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, modis

I'm currently trying to find a way to extract site location data from Google Earth Engine for several MODIS products in its original projection (sinusoidal). Yet I have not managed to receive the exact pixel values as provided from MODIS itself.

So far I have used the commands like this.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

def _data_extract(site_id, sensor, lon, lat, radius, product, bands, res, start, end):

    geometry = ee.Geometry.Point(lon, lat).buffer(radius)

    col = ee.ImageCollection(product).\
                    filterDate(start, end);


projection = col.first().pixelLonLat().projection()

data2 = col.getRegion(geometry, int(res), projection.crs()).getInfo()

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data2[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = data2[0])
```

See this blog post for more info: https://mygeoblog.com/2017/01/13/your-gee-data-in-pandas/